# XSLT in a UIWebView using iOS SDK 4.2

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, mobile-safari, xslt, ios-4.2

Is it possible to use XSLT in a UIWebView using iOS SDK 4.2?  Alternatively, is it possible to use XSLT in iOS SDK 4.2 outside of a UIWebView?  I have seen similar questions to this, but they seem to be dated and refer to pre-4.0 iOS SDKs.

If it is possible, a link to a simple iOS XSLT example would be great too.

TIA.

Comment: "Possible" also means in a way acceptable to Apple and their AppStore.

Comment: hi erik.. were you able to find the solution to this one? I am stuck with this same problem...

Comment: learner2010: see my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is yes.  Here's an example:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSString *xml = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"greeting.xsl\"?><greeting>Hello, World!</greeting>";
[self.webView loadData:[xml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] MIMEType:@"text/xml" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:baseURL];
```

I was having problems with this because I was trying to load XML using the UIWebView's

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

method.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. I had come across your post earlier but had a doubt.. so just the above piece of code would work right? we would not need to use the loadHTMLString function right?

Comment: It's been a while since I coded this, but if memory serves, the loadHTMLString won't do any XSLT processing.  The loadData code does.

Comment: I have a question.. in the above piece of code, If I am getting the xml from the webservice, how would I add the `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="trial.xsl"?>` code to the xml?

Comment: Also, could you tell me where should I be storing the `xsl` file?

Comment: Put the xsl file in your main bundle.