# How to display a particular NSXmlparser response data to webview

Tags: iphone

I parsed my xml by using NSXMLParser and I got the data of like `<title>,<details>,<subtitle>` now I just want to publish this data on the UIWebView.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've parsed your data already, you have it stored in a set of variables, right?

You could substitute it into some HTML using `stringWithFormat:`, and then display it in a web view with

```
[myWebView loadHTMLString:aString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

Alternatively, instead of parsing yout XML at all, you could just use XSLT to style it directly: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100051/xlst-in-a-uiwebview-using-ios-sdk-4-2) if you want to go that route.