# NodeJS detect either the client(mobile) is a browser or an application?

Tags: android, ios, node.js, express, user-agent

I have developed a simple REST api using NODE and EXPRESS. And I already have a web-app(browser) and a native mobile application.
Now I need to check if the incoming request is from web-browser or from native application.

I have successfully detected the device for incoming request coming from browser via `USER-AGENT`.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest using the `Host` header.
For example:
If your web application is hosted at `example.com` then all requests will have Host header set to `example.com`.
In your mobile application, you can manually set all request headers to have a different Host header like `Host:app.example.com`.

A good practice to have limited set of hostnames that accepted by the server.

Make sure you do not tight any security logic to that header. Every HTTP client can fake/override that value.

Answer (score -3):

window.navigator.standalone for iOS, and `window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches` for Android to detect this:

```
isInWebAppiOS = (window.navigator.standalone == true);
isInWebAppChrome = (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches);
```

Set a cookie for each to pass to the server.

**References**

- [Optimized Presentation of XML Content | Introduction](http://www.informit.com/articles/printerfriendly/677911)
- [Android 8.0 Compatibility Definition  |  Android Open Source Project](https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd)
- [Issues - chromium - An open-source project to help move the web forward. - Monorail](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?can=1&q=accept%20header%20component%3AMobile%3EWebView)
- [143578 – Chrome: XMLHttpRequest executed in UIWebView encodes valid query string characters](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=143578)
- [Browser Shredders: iOS UIWebView baseURL](http://browser-shredders.blogspot.com/2014/02/ios-uiwebview-baseurl.html)
- [iOS - Best Practices for Opening a Web Page Within an App - Outbrain Developer Center](http://developer.outbrain.com/ios-best-practices-for-opening-a-web-page-within-an-app/)
- [CWE - CWE-749: Exposed Dangerous Method or Function (2.11)](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/749.html)
- [Attack Surface Extended by URL Schemes (pdf)](https://conference.hitb.org/hitbsecconf2017ams/materials/D2T2%20-%20Yu%20Hong%20-%20Attack%20Surface%20Extended%20by%20URL%20Schemes.pdf)
- [Implementing XSLT into our iOS Apps | The Distance, York](https://thedistance.co.uk/ios/xslt-on-ios/)
- [How to transform xml with xslt and display it in Android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318998/how-to-transform-xml-with-xslt-and-display-it-in-android-webview)
- [XSLT in a UIWebView using iOS SDK 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100051/xlst-in-a-uiwebview-using-ios-sdk-4-2)
- [detect ipad/iphone webview via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460205/detect-ipad-iphone-webview-via-javascript)
- [is-webview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-webview)

Comment: Question is how to detect this in NodeJS - The window object doesn't exist in node.. :(